# How google oauth tokens can use to sign user in Nodejs RESTapi

Tags: node.js, react-native, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

We have a project.

1. Nodejs RESTapi
2. React native mobile app

I followed a tutorial about Google oAuth signin / signup in Nodejs. There basically front end sends and access token to the back-end and the back-end verify that token with the Google, If that token is valid back-end generates a JWT token and pass to the front-end.

I think this follow will nicely working with the Single page applications,
but I don't know how this gonna be work with react native mobile apps. Because, according to the tutorial that access token get expired.

I have no idea what should I do after that token expired?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you also get a refresh_token that it is used to renew the main access_token. 
The access_token has a limited lifetime, but the refresh_token never expires unless you remove the authorization on Google's side. In that case you need to ask the client to login via Google's OAuth once again.